# Why protocol families macros and address families macros are duplicated

Tags: linux, sockets

In bits/socket.h of Linux systems, the address families macros are defined in terms of protocol families macros. there is a one-to-one correspondence among them with the form of

```
#define AF_something PF_something
```

Since the one-to-to mapping between the AF macros and the PF macros, they seem like unnecessary duplications.

My question is: is there a reason for this?

Comment: IMHO this is a bug. Both sets of constants are allocated by IANA, and they *happen* to have this mapping, but there is nothing at IANA that justifies defining one set in terms of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original idea was to have address and protocol families independent. An address can potentially be used in various protocols. Authors expected that for example IPv4 address can be used by another hypothetical protocol different than IP. And vice versa - independent families are prepared to use a new kind of addresses in IP protocol.

So the only reason is that author of the socket API wanted to be future proof. As far as I know there is still one to one mapping between PF and AF.

It is a good habit to follow the original idea. That means have independent constant and use PF constants when working with protocol for example creating socket: `s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` and use AF constant when working with addresses for example `sa.sin_family = AF_INET`.